# vb.net code to download the sql server 2014 express and silent installtion

Tags: vb.net, http, download, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to create a executable using vb.net. Which will download SQL Server 2014 Express and install it. It should pick up the appropriate installer from the Microsoft site. and the install without user interaction on local machine.

I am able to run the set up through code. But I have to download the installer manually. So looking for some help how to make a call to Microsoft site and select appropriate installer and download it on my local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create an installer (MSI) project in Visual Studio, and make use of boostrapper packages.

Here's the link from Microsoft (old but still applies): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/11/21/creating-an-installer-that-includes-a-visual-studio-bootstrapper-package-and-an-msi-built-with-wix-3-0/

Another option is to use clickonce deployments:
[Installing SQL Server 2014 Express package as ClickOnce prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560419/installing-sql-server-2014-express-package-as-clickonce-prerequisite)

Comment: Thanks but we still we have to extract it before we run setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to download a file from the internet.You might want to download the file to your own server and use this code to get it from there.

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim proxy As WebProxy = New WebProxy()
proxy.Address = New Uri("Your Proxy Address. Don't use proxy if you don't need it.")
proxy.Credentials = creds
wc.Proxy = proxy
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other")
wc.DownloadFile("http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/ExpressAndTools%2032BIT/SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe", "C:\SQL Server 2014 Express.exe")
```

**Edit**
I included the direct download link from Microsoft. The link is for SQL Server 2014 Express x86 with SSMS. I tested this code to work.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate response . But it still needs to extract exe before it run set up

Comment: What do you mean extract the exe? Please edit your question to include this part about extracting an exe.